# Exclude from display "Re geocode" and "Delete" checkboxes

Tags: 7, location

I would like to totally exclude from rendering "Re geocode" and "Delete" checkboxes of the "Location" module:
 - I searched for an option in the configuration sections of my installation of Drupal and I did not find anything;
 - I tried to intercept the creation of the form with `hook_form_organisation_node_form_alter()`, but I did not find the checkboxes in the `$form` and `$form_state` variables.

For the moment I hide the two 'divs' containing the HTML code, but I would like not to send the code to the web browser. I would prefer a clean solution, so is there any way to do it? A hook function I don't know can help me?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/164831/10729