# How to get rid of Re geocode and delete radio boxes on Location module?

Tags: 7, location

How can I remove the ReGeocode and Delete checkboxes from the [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module? I don't need these functions and there is no settings to delete them.

Where is the PHP or html file located so I can manually delete the lines of code? I searched for it but can't find it anywhere.

```
<label for="edit-locations-0-re-geocode-location">Re geocode </label>

<label for="edit-locations-0-delete-location">Delete </label>
```

I think these are the lines I need to delete?

Comment: Related Drupal org issue that has some solutions: https://www.drupal.org/node/381458#comment-10807926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a template to edit the location module's form elements. You'll need to alter its form element. You can drop the following functions into a custom module to alter the form element so that it doesn't display the Recode/Delete checkboxes.

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if(isset($type['location_element'])) {
    $type['location_element']['#after_build'][] ='MYMODULE_location_element_post_render';
  }
}
function MYMODULE_location_element_post_render($element, &$form_state) {
  $element['delete_location']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $element['re_geocode_location']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, would be worth it to publish this module for others to use?

Comment: A module is probably overkill for one piece of functionality. With a little reworking, it would probably make a good patch to the Location module for anyone else needing this functionality.